# Hibernate transactions rolling back in tomcat server

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat7

I am encountering a very weird problem in production. I have deployed a new application in production which is run in Tomcat server(version 7) using Windows services. This application is basically a batch processing which processes around 100-200 records at a time and generates their output in a flat file. When we run this application in production, the record's status changes from pending to verified(which is correct) and generates the flat file without any exception. However, when the batch process completes, all transactions are rolled back like nothing happened. Means, the record's status changes to pending, flat file is empty etc. This same application when running in staging or QA environment, it is running fine.

Can someone help me with this problem or at least guide me where should I start looking into it?

Since I don't know where the problem is, I am not attaching any sources or any error logs. Please let me know what details should I share?

Thank you

Comment: is there any exception is coming .have you catch exception?

Comment: Yes catching all exceptions but logs do not show any exception.

Comment: without logs its difficult to understand what issue your facing? i can understand as its prod logs. As its hibernates if there is any exception with caching or while processing even in last record it will rollback all records from starting.

Comment: Could you please tell me which logs should I refer? I have sysouts on my code and they seem to be printing as expected.

Comment: Better add log in your persistence layer and try rerunning it. it will log if record is processed correctly and stops when particular records causes exception which will rollback everything. i know it wont solve issue but at least you will figure out the record which is causing issue

Comment: if you will get any excpetion then you can try @Transactional(noRollbackFor=youExceptionName.class) this will prevent rollback operation